# Using jQuery AJAX call with Spring MVC project to load a div based on what was clicked

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

I'm wondering what might be the best approach if I were to want to handle the need to load a div with details based on what a user clicks in a table full of a recordset returned by a DB stored procedure.

I essentially have the following so far:

*EJournalForm.java (Model)*

*eJournal.jsp (View)*

*EJournalController.java (Controller)*

*ejournal.js (Mostly just has the jQuery for `onclick` handling so far)*

*EJournalDetail.hbm.xml (hibernate for sproc)*

*EJournalData.java (represents result set returned by sproc)*

What I'm trying to accomplish in my view is to basically load the div with an id of `"ejdetails"` with data about a record that was output in the table using an `onclick` event. I currently have the "details" represented as a String in my EJournalData.java file, if I need to I could tweak this to get the details in a separate DB call, but currently, we just don't display it in the table since it is meant to be in the  beside it.

Below, we basically load these sections based on search criteria I haven't provided in this post since it isn't too important, I think.

Snippet from eJournal.jsp (ignore the inline styling, it isn't perfected yet and I know this needs to go in the CSS files eventually) :

```
    <div class="ejresults" style="height: 400px; width: 45%; overflow-y: auto; float:left;">
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:33%">
                    Trans #
                </td>
                <td style="width:33%">
                    Register #
                </td>
                <td style="width:33%">
                    Trans Date
                </td>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="eJournal" items="${ej.ejList}">
                <tr class="ejresult">
                    <td class="ejresult" style="width:33%">
                        <c:out value="${eJournal.transactionNumberResult}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="ejresult" style="width:33%">
                        <c:out value="${eJournal.registerNumberResult}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="ejresult" style="width:33%">
                        <c:out value="${eJournal.transactionDateResult}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="ejdetails" style="height: 400px; width: 45%; overflow-y: auto; float:right;">
        <c:forEach var="eJournal" items="${ej.ejList}" end="0">
            <c:out value="${eJournal.eJournalDetails}" escapeXml="false"/>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
```

I've at least got to the point of handling the click event and loading the details  with *something* (I might want to clear out the div in some cases anyway), but the best practice in doing an AJAX call for this is what I'm not sure of.

```
$(function() {

// Clear ejournal details, then load ejournal details
$( ".ejresult" ).click(function() {
    //event.preventDefault();   
    $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
    $( this ).addClass("highlight");
    $( "#ejdetails" ).html( "Cleared." );
});

});
```

Currently, you'll notice in the details  that on page load we actually load the details about the first element in the result set already. It might be possible to still retrieve those details without making another database call just for that  since they were loaded into the array of journal data objects, but just not displayed at first, or it might be best I develop a separate .jsp, model, view, and controller just for those details since .load() seems to be best for loading an entire view (and in turn the java and DB calls behind it) asynchronously.

Advice? Feel free to ask me if you need any other snippets for proper feedback or ideas on best practices or approaches.

Comment: In this case it would probably be easier and cleaner for you to use load() - http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I am starting to believe you're right as well, Jay. I've performed similar tasks using .load(), and it may actually be a better design that way. I've used .load() before and it is incredibly simple in doing that by just setting up a new View.